# Independence of Function of Random Vectors

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

For $i=1,2$, let $X_i(k)$ be positive random variables which are i.i.d. in $k = 0,1,2 \dots.$. Now we form two random vectors:
$$Y:=[X_1(0)X_1(1) \;\; X_2(0)X_2(1)]^T$$
and
$$Z=[X_1(3) \;\; X_2(3)]^T$$

I wonder if $Y$ and $Z$ are **independent** random vectors?

My guess is **not**. While we have component-wise independence (in this case, we have $X_1(0)X_1(1)$ is independent of $X_1(3)$ and $X_2(0)X_2(1)$ is independent of $X_2(3)$), it does not imply mutual independence in general. Is my thinking correct? Any comment/suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thinking is right. For any given i.i.d sequence $(X_1(k): k \geq 0)$ we can construct an i.i.d sequence  $(X_2(k): k \geq 0)$ such that $X_1(0)X_1(1)=X_2(3)$. In this case then first component of $Y$ is same as the second component of $Z$ so $Y$ and $Z$ are not independent as long as $X_1(0)X_1(1)$ is not almost surely constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I totally get it.